# How to use mod rewrite URL with value contain (-) in value?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my code for `test.php`

.

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$id_val = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_mysqli,$_GET['id_val']);
echo $id_val;
?>
```

This is my mod rewrite code (`.htaccess`)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^test/([^-]*)$ /test.php?id_val=$1 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

When i tried to access

```
www.example.com/test/8-pi7Tvu66
```

It's not working. (It's will be redirect to index.php and not echo anything.)

But when i tried to access

```
www.example.com/test.php?id_val=8-pi7Tvu66
```

It's work good. (echo 8-pi7Tvu66)

How can i do for work good on mod rewrite URL ?

```
www.example.com/test/8-pi7Tvu66
```

...

Remark : I still tried to test on id_val that not contain (-)

```
eg:
    www.example.com/test/8pi7Tvu66
```

And it's work good. (echo 8pi7Tvu66)

Comment: Don't rely on `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL injection, [it alone is not sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string). You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: i use `mysqli_real_escape_string` and `mysqli` it's can not protect me from SQL injection ?

Comment: @mamiw It is not that it cannot protect you, it is that using `mysqli_real_escape...` is more difficult to "get correct".  The generally accepted and easier/better method uses prepared statements.  See @AlexHowansky's links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RewriteRule has the following regex:

```
^test/([^-]*)$
```

which explicitly matches everything *except* a dash. You can change it to

```
^test/(.*)$
```

if you want it to match all characters.

Comment: So use `^test/(.+)$` is the better morethan `^test/([^-]*)$` ?

Comment: If your issue is that `-` isn't working, then yes. This will add that character to the accepted list (since currently it's the only one that won't work).

Comment: When i use ^test/(.+)$ all sign are working on my code ? `EG: _ + -` ?

Comment: Yes, `(.+)` matches **everything**

Comment: And it's will be make my site to hack ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're concerned about hacking. The only difference between the two expressions in my answer is that `-` will work in the second one - everything else is already valid in the first one. This answers your question.